# How to make 3 phone calls sequentially one after another programatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am newbie to android.i write this code for make a call

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I know there is a listener to find the state of the phone using this code.

```
  private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
  public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
  try {
  switch (state) {
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
  Toast.makeText(CaptureCall.this, "CALL_STATE_RINGING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
  Toast.makeText(CaptureCall.this, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
  case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
  Toast.makeText(CaptureCall.this, "CALL_STATE_IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
  default:
  Toast.makeText(CaptureCall.this, "default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  Log.i("Default", "Unknown phone state=" + state);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   Log.i("Exception", "PhoneStateListener() e = " + e);
  }
 }
};
```

Actually I call the first number and listen for the state of the phone. If the phone state changes to `IDLE` I call the second number. But it is not working.

Any one plz suggest me how to do that task.

Comment: We do not know what "it is not work" mean. Be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Can you call the first number using the following?

```
       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
       intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + bundle.getString("mobilePhone")));
       context.startActivity(intent);
```

If no, add the following too.

```
       intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

And call the second phone number using the same code to call the first number in the IDLE state.

But be careful that the IDLE state will be true even before you start calling the first number, in this case your second number will be called first.  In the IDLE state, you can set a flag if the first number is called then start calling the second number.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, You are trying to call a number after completion of previous call.

**Here is Algorithm** for calling n numbers sequentially

1. Make Queue of numbers to call
2. Create and register Broadcast Receiver for PhoneState
3. Dequeue element and fire Intent for Call
4. Broadcast receiver created at point 2 will listen for call drop state 
   which is IDLE state,
5. if theres more element in queue repeat step 3-4
6. else, unregister broadcast receiver.

**C# Code Snippet:**

```
                Queue phoneNumbers = new Queue();


                foreach (var contact in emergencyContacts)
                    phoneNumbers.Enqueue(contact.contactNo);

                ShareUtils.CallToNumber(context, phoneNumbers.Dequeue().ToString());
                var callReceiver = new CallReceiver();
                callReceiver.onReceive += (intent) =>
                {
                    if (intent.Extras.GetString(TelephonyManager.ExtraState).Equals(TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle))
                    {
                        if (phoneNumbers.Count > 0)
                        {
                            var phNumber = phoneNumbers.Dequeue().ToString();
                            ShareUtils.CallToNumber(context, phNumber);
                            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, $"Calling {phNumber}", ToastLength.Long).Show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.UnregisterReceiver(callReceiver);
                            ((LandingActivityNew)this.Activity)?.LoadSOS_SuccessFragment();
                        }
                    }
                };
                context.RegisterReceiver(callReceiver, new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"));
```